# Deploy wordpress site with capistrano

Tags: wordpress

I am trying to deploy a wordpress site using capistrano.  Here is my deploy.rb file.

```
# config valid only for current version of Capistrano
lock "3.11.0"

set :deploy_to, "/home/#{fetch(:deploy_user)}/#{fetch(:application)}"


set :ssh_options, {
  forward_agent: true,
}


set :pty, true


set :keep_releases, 5


set :linked_files, %w{wp-activate.php wp-blog-header.php wp-comments-post.php wp-config.php wp-cron.php wp-links-opml.php wp-load.php wp-login.php wp-mail.php wp-settings.php wp-signup.php wp-trackback.php xmlrpc.php wp-content/index.php wp-content/themes/index.php index.php .htaccess}


set :linked_dirs, fetch(:linked_dirs, []).push('wp-content/plugins','wp-content/uploads','wp-admin','wp-includes','wp-content/upgrade','wp-content/themes/twentyfifteen','wp-content/themes/twentysixteen','wp-content/themes/twentyseventeen')
```

Everything seems to be working correctly apart from when I upload a theme it puts it in the /shared/wp-content/themes folder and not the current/wp-content/themes folder.

My apache vhost file is set up as follows

```
<Directory /home/user/app/current/>
        Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
        AllowOverride All
    Require all granted
</Directory>
```

Where's it getting the path from?

Reading the documentation which says

> You cannot move the themes folder because its path is hardcoded relative to the wp-content folder:

It's seems to be picking up the wp-content folder from app/shared, not app/current.  The one in app/current is not a symlink to the one in app/shared

Answer (score 1):

Re-ran wordpress install script.  Now works fine.